# Nvidia Optimus card does not work?

Tags: 10.04, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, hybrid

My notebook (ASUS A40J Series) comes with hybrid graphics: nVIDIA GF310M and Intel.

I can't use the nVIDIA card in my machine and am using Ubuntu 10.04.

How can I get this work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laptop with Nvidia Optimus](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/laptop-with-nvidia-optimus)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at acpi_call and bumblebee in this website:
http://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux
Also, please provide your DSDT info as explained in this website:
http://linux-hybrid-graphics.blogspot.com/

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at my setup for a Dell XPS17 L702x, it should work for your Acer: [(from web.archive.org) Ubuntu 11.10 Oneric on Dell XPS17 L702x](http://web.archive.org/web/20111220031434/https://www.cmdematos.com/2011/10/ubuntu-1110-oneric-on-dell-xps17-l702x.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling optimus from BIOS if bumblebee doesn´t work. I solved that way, and installed nvidia-current from x-swat updates repository, because regular repo driver crashed when it was installed.